# controller throwing javascript error

Tags: javascript, aura, javascript-controller

I have a very basic controller function which is for some reason throwing a Javascript error.

HTML where controller is called:

```
<lightning:button label="Apply" iconName="utility:magicwand" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.applyCodeToOrder}" />
```

controller:

```
({
    applyCodeToOrder : function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('test');
        console.log('test');
    }
})
```

I tried to use debugging console to find a relevant looking error, but this is all that i could come up with (it's what is highlighted in aura.prod.js):

```
aD {name: "applyCodeToOrder", g: "c:trac_PromotionCode$controller$applyCodeToOrder", ei: "CLIENT", qj: ƒ, mh: {…}, …}
```

More of the error message:

```
H.prototype.run = H.prototype.ab;
H.prototype.Nc = function(a) {
    $A.assert(this.Da && this.Da.Vo(), lx);
    if (1 !== this.D.H) {
        this.state = Om;
        hB($A.d, this.D);
        try {
            var b = $A.X.kg(this.D)
              , c = $A.X.zw(b, a);
            this.returnValue = this.qj.call(m, b, c, this.D.helper); //this.returnValue is undefined
            this.state = Xm //value of 'state' is "Running", Xm is "SUCCESS"
        } catch (d) {
            yD(this, d)
        } finally {
            iB($A.d)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share error message or other error details

Comment: Hey @SunilAware thanks, when the javascript crashes, it highlights `this`, and when i hover my mouse over it it says the 1st error message in show in my question. I have expanded my question to show that entire function that surrounds that specific error message

Comment: @SunilAware I also added some important values. Could it matter that `this.returnValue` is undefined?

Comment: It wont shows any error I tried in dev org it works fine, issue might occur due to other markup, can you share component markup and any other controller code ?

Comment: I can't replicated it... I wondered if the `apply` could be causing issues, as it's a reserved word in Js, but it had no issues. Check you are logged in?